# Javascript and SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to dynamically create SVG vectors with Javascript and I'm running into some problems.

I create the svg markup in javascript with `document.createElement` and append it to a div container. Then I do the same thing and create a `rect` and add it as a child to the svg id.

When I look at the DOM, I can see the elements being added, and their properties are such:

```
<svg id="gdc_container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="300">
    <rect id="gdc_background" width="500" height="300" style="rgb(0,0,255)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Everything looks fine, however the graphics are not showing up. When I use Chromes inspector, I can see the svg and rect elements, but the chrome tooltip shows their size as [ 0 x 0 ].

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using `createElementNS`? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS), for some examples look at http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/shapes/js_dom/index.htm.

Comment: Write that as an answer and you have the checkmark! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using `createElementNS`? ([developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS))

For some examples look at http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/shapes/js_dom/index.htm.

Comment: Tried using one of the examples for shapes.  I inserted the code block inside a window.onload and there's no shape appearing.

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you create a fiddle showing the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to check the fiddle. Svg elements need to be inside an svg document to be properly rendered(also your fiddle needs the "no wrap <...>" rule to work. Check http://jsfiddle.net/w9gEx/1/